# Placing one layout above another layout in the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a black view and placing it on top of another view as can be seen in the image below. So far so good.

But I can't figure out how to place the black view in the bottom of the screen? (still on top of the white pdf background...)

[image]

Here is my xml code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/background_pdf"
        android:layout_below="@+id/background_pdf2"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >
    <com.radaee.pdf.MLPDFViewer
        android:id="@+id/pdf"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/background_pdf2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75px"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
             />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I add the following code `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to              `android:id="@+id/background_pdf2"` my result is the following:

[image]

As you can see the black view is placed at the bottom but the main-view (white pdf) dissapears. I don't understand this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to your Linear layout with id background_pdf2, like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/background_pdf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.radaee.pdf.MLPDFViewer
            android:id="@+id/pdf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/background_pdf2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75px"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please remove android:layout_below="@+id/background_pdf2" in your Linear layout "background_pdf"